# Start the Chainlink Node - Connection Refused

Tags: chainlink

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC2nL.jpg)Code ran...

cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.9 local n

Error recieved...

error starting app: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8546: connect: connection refused

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Earlson, In order to solve this issue please share your environmental file (.env) and blacken all sensitive data like API-keys or credentials.

Comment: Screenshot added to the original comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is a syntax issue of your environmental file. Please remove the quotation marks `"` by `ETH_URL` and `Database_URL`.
Also please ensure that both variables are set just one time inside of your environmental. (you have them added multiple times)

Your environmental finally needs to look like this:

```
ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=42
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
ETH_URL=wss://eth-kovan.alchemyapi.io/v2/xxxxxxx
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://xxxx
```

Comment: The node appears to be running. Able to access local host landing page via HTTP://localhost:6688 , but issue logging in via LocalHost. The message "your email or password is incorrect. Please try again" appeared. Please advise. Thank you.